# Is it possible to have a separate animation timeline in another layer?

Tags: animation, timeline

I would like to have different animation speeds for different objects in the same scene. Having a separate timeline would help but I can't find an option to do that.

If it is not possible to create a separate timeline, what should I do to have different animation speeds?

Comment: You could try NLA editor for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved my goal by simply increasing the needed amount of timeline frames and duplicating and extending everything I need to be short into a loopable manner.
This way I can animate different objects to go faster or slower in the same scene.

Comment: NLA (Non Linear Editor) is your friend